# antd onChange is firing three times with each key stroke

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have the following form in `antd` with code taken almost verbatim from [the official website](https://ant.design/components/form/). Code sandbox is also [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-darwin-xjy71):

The problem with the below code is that on every key stroke in the field, the onChange method fires three (3) times. You can verify that in the codesandbox link as well if you open the browser console. I would like to understand why is that and what can be done about it.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form, Input } from 'antd';

import {FieldData} from 'rc-field-form/es/interface.d.ts';
interface CustomizedFormProps {
  onChange: (fields: FieldData[]) => void;
  fields: FieldData[];
}


const CustomizedForm: React.FC<CustomizedFormProps> = ({ onChange, fields }) => {
  return (
    <Form
      name="global_state"
      layout="inline"
      fields={fields}
      onFieldsChange={(changedFields, allFields) => {
        onChange(allFields);
      }}
    >
      <Form.Item
        name="username"
        label="Username"
        rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Username is required!' }]}
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

export class AntdFormTest extends React.Component<{}, {fields: FieldData[]}> {
  
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {fields: [{name: ['username'], value: 'Ant Design'}]};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <CustomizedForm
          fields={this.state.fields}
          onChange={newFields => {
            console.log('onChange fired');
            this.setState({fields: newFields});
          }}
        />
        <pre className="language-bash">{JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 2)}</pre>
      </>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: cannot run the sandbox. sth worng with the files. you forgot to save them? `antd-form` is empty

Comment: @Apostolos should be ok now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `onValuesChange` method instead. The `onFieldsChange` is fired when a field is updated(rerendered). See more here: https://ant.design/components/form/#API

[Here](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-global-state) it explains when you should use the `OnFieldsChange` method

Comment: Yes, this works. However, I am now able to use `onValuesChange` with a Redux store (on the real application - not the code I posted). Yet your answer seems to imply that `onValuesChange` should be used when the form data is saved in the component's state whereas, when using Redux, `onFieldsChange` should be used. Am I reading you right or am I OK using onValuesChange with a Redux store?

Comment: The only difference I see between those two is that the onFieldsChange also includes `allFields` as the second argument so that it will be easier for you to dispatch the whole "form data" payload instead of the changed fields/values only. Using the onValuesChange will also do the trick for you if you don't follow the data pattern that is used for the form fields:

[
  {
    "name": [
      "username"
    ],
    "value": "Ant Design"
  }
].   
I recommend using the onValuesChange so that to avoid excess dispatch actions due to their 3 rerenders

Comment: `onValuesChange` also includes `allValues` and that's what I dispatch in the action. In fact, it's shape is similar to what I have in my Redux store so it requires less processing.

Comment: Cool. I guess the onFieldsChange is also used when you create forms with dynamic fields and store their data in Redux